# Redirect non-www to WWW error with subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain

I need to force WWW on my website.

So I used this htacces:

```
#Redirect non-www to WWW
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Problem is that http://subdomain.mydomain.com 
will be redirected to http://www.subdomain.mydomain.com

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this on subdomains, you just a condition which matches only the main domain and not `www.` This version will match very generically, any domain which has two parts and doesn't begin with www, not matching any domain with 3 parts where the first isn't www.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Doesn't start with www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# And does not also have a subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[a-z0-9_-]+\.[a-z0-9_-]+\.[a-z0-9_-]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this is simpler if you have a *fixed* set of domains to deal with. Instead of checking for starting with `www`, do the redirect only when it matches the bare domain. Add as many domain names into the `( | )` OR grouping as needed.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Matching any of 3 domains without www, and no subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain1|domain2|domain3)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: second code will redirect me to www.mydomain.com.com (with two .com)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect only the main domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$0 [R,L]
```

Never test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.